# Change directory ownership on mounted drive

Tags: mount, permissions, root

I have a dual-boot Windows 10/Xubuntu 16.04 set up. Both share the small SSD for boot, and both have home directories on the data drives.

For Xubuntu, `/dev/sdc` is the data drive, and it's mounted at `/mnt/archives`. When I ran `usermod -d /mnt/archives/mike mike` against my user to move my home drive to the data drive, it worked just fine after a reboot. When I originally changed my home directory, I had `/dev/sdc` mount under `id=0,gid=0`, which was mounting everything as root. I changed the mount to `id=mike,gid=mount_group`, and rebooted my computer. However, when I go to run `sudo chown -R mike:mount_group /mnt/archives/mike/*`, it doesn't actually change any of the permissions. :/

Here is my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdd3 during installation
UUID=8db38c8f-87b6-4174-a439-fd60dbb7b313 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/sdc /mnt/archives auto rw,relatime,user_id=mike,group_id=mount_group,allow_other,blksize=4096
```

Here is a sample of the directory:

```
# ls -lah /mnt/archives/mike/
total 88K
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8.0K Oct 23 15:50 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4.0K Oct 23 14:30 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Oct  3 23:05 .adobe
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4.0K Oct  3 23:36 anaconda2
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Oct  9 00:14 .astropy
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Oct  9 00:19 .aws
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6.5K Oct 23 15:49 .bash_history
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  220 Oct  3 22:24 .bash_logout
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  948 Oct 23 14:33 .bash_profile
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3.8K Oct 23 14:34 .bashrc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3.7K Oct  3 23:36 .bashrc-anaconda2.bak
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4.0K Oct 23 16:01 .cache
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Oct  8 17:21 .conda
...
```

How can I fix this odd permissions issue?

Comment: `sdc` is a drive, not a partition, is this drive not partitioned? What is the used file-system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your `chmod -R` command.  The `*` in the command is excluding the actual `mike/` portion of your space.  By default the `*` doesn't see the dot `.` in the intended immediate directory.

These are commands that will achieve what you are looking for.  First, it's common for users to mistakenly change owner of their home's root director or some of the files and folders in their space.  This can be corrected with:

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/
```

or in the case of the command in your question, use this:

```
$ sudo chown -R mike:mount_group /mnt/archives/mike/
```

Comment: I would user `$USER` instead of `$(whoami)`

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks.  I was aware of the USER variable, but wasn't sure if all the shells used the same specification ("$USER" OR "$LOGNAME").  I know they will all have the `/usr/bin/whoami`.  I checked and tested popular shells and find the as suggested $USER is set in all of them.  Thanks for adding to my experience!  I updated my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: hehehe.Well I have several systems where whoami does not work ;-)

Comment: Oh, so basically it was the globbing that was messing it up?

Comment: @Rinzwind Will you respond to mynameismevin's comment concerning globbing?  Thanks!